# ListPlot points labeled in different way

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have plot a list of points by ListPlot, and I want to be able to label these points.

**Basic codes:**

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}] -> ToString /@ Range[-1, 4], PlotStyle -> {Red}]
```

Now I want the label style like "a1, a2, ..."(Subscript is best), I changed the codes

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}] -> StringJoin["a", #] & /@ Map[ToString, Range[-1, 4]], PlotStyle -> {Red}]
```

but there is no point was labeled, I don't know why, the String list length still 6 (`Length[StringJoin["a", #] & /@ Map[ToString, Range[-1, 4]]]`), how does it show the labels?

Comment: replace `StringJoin["a", #] & /@ Map[ToString, Range[-1, 4]]` with `(StringJoin["a", #] & /@ Map[ToString, Range[-1, 4]])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
rr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}];
ListPlot[rr -> (Subscript["a", #] & /@ Range[-1, 4]), PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]